# Before-the-dot-in-a-file-name, what is it called?

Tags: filenames, nomenclature

After-the-dot-in-a-file-name, it is called extension.

Comment: http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1="filename+and+extension"&word2="basename+and+extension"

Comment: I think Googlefight is broken.  It says "Basename and extension" wins, even though "Filename and extension" beats it by a 30 to 1 ratio on an ordinary Google search.

Comment: I see the StackOverflow police have found us. :O

Comment: @Robert Harvey. I see 12700 results for "filename and extension" and 833 results for "basename and extension"

Comment: Interesting.  I'm getting 27100 for "filename and extension...

Comment: ... and now I'm getting 170,000 for "basename and extension" ?!

Comment: Haha. Now I'll know what to suggest the next time someone asks for a random number generator. :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's called the basename. In fact, there's a unix/linux command for it:

> basename - strip directory and suffix
>   from filenames

Comment: The `basename` I have only removes the suffix if you specify exactly what you want removed; it does not remove a suffix by default.

Comment: Aye. The idea is the same, though.

Comment: `"The basename I have only removes the suffix if you specify exactly what you want removed"` - yeh, PHP is not very consistent with this :(

Answer (score 5):

The "base name," "basename," "primary name," "filename," "file name," or the "file."

Comment: I think we can agree that these are all interchangeable.

Comment: I'd never use "filename" and "basename" interchangeably. They mean different things.

Comment: I don't really agree with filename or file name. Don't most OS' consider the extension to be part of the filename?

Comment: I hear "type the filename and the extension" all the time. It's a very common usage.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the ambiguousness of filename. In `c:/program.exe`, filename either refers to `Program` or the entire string as a whole.

Comment: Common by people outside of IT maybe, but we should know better :P

Comment: Historically, some systems have mandatory extensions and some have optional extensions. When the extension is mandatory, it can be seen as metadata, and the basename and the filename are the same thing

Answer (score 4):

Base name or file name.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby calls it the [basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/File.html#M000803). That's a good, succinct name that I generally go with in other environments too.

Answer (score 2):

Basename or primary file name.

Answer (score 2):

I call it filename. So its like Filename.ext

Answer (score 1):

I've always called the everything before the dot and the extension the "file name".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby or Linux guy, so I guess I missed the BaseName thing.  It makes for all sorts of interesting naming convention hilarity.  I'm in the

```
Filename.Ext
```

camp, although that, too can be a FileName. (or maybe a FileNameWithExtension).

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, the term Leafname was used, although that typically included the extension.
I mention this for historical value, and since its dropped out of usage, it might be redeemable for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The boost::filesystem library calls it basename as well.